# Decrypted Hash and Encrypted hash

Tags: web, hash

If this password's ( qwqwqw123456 ) hash is   `$2a$07$sijdbfYKmgWdcGhPPn$$$.C98C0wmy6jsqA3fUKODD0OFBKJkHdn.`

What is the password of this hash `$2a$07$sijdbfYKmgWdcGhPPn$$$.9PTdICzon3EUNHZvOOXgTY4z.UTQTqG`

And Can I know which hash algorithm is it ?

Comment: Hashes aren't *meant* to allow two-way decryption. The point is that it's one-way...

Comment: @Jon Skeet I was wondering if you know this hash algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to guess which algorithm was used,
depending on the format and length of the hash,
your known value etc. but there is no definitive way to know it.

And the purpose of any "hash" function is
that it is NOT reversible/decryptable/whatever.

Depending on some factors you could try to guess the original value too
(Brute force attack: Try to hash all possible values and check which hash
is equal to yours) but, depending on the count of possibilities,
the used algortihm etc. that could take millions of years. (you could also be lucky
and get the correct value within short time, but that´s unlikely).
There are other things than bruteforce-ing, but in the end,
it´s pretty much impossible to reverse a good hash function